# How to removes spaces with this RegEx

Tags: .net, regex, match, removing-whitespace

My input is

```
Engineering | AB7407 | 007412665 | Jackie Browne | Drawing for Construction
```

and the regex is

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]+ \| ){2})[^|]+
```

I am using the above `RegEx` to extract 007412665. It works, however it brings spaces before and after the value.

I tried `/s` but it did not remove the spaces. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of your current regex you only need to make a minor modification.

Instead of this one:

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]+ \| ){2})[^|]+
```

Use this one:

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]+\| ){2})[^| ]+
```

Here's the Regex hero to test it: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=92183ab8-4fa4-4d9a-bd7b-278c11a77bd1